# I am getting errors while installing ember add on ember-cli-tutorial-style,

Tags: ember.js, ember-addon

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zxrd.jpg)

below versions of node, npm and ember-cli i am using...

ember-cli: 2.18.0
node: 8.9.4
os: win32 ia32
npm : 5.6.0

please guide me how to address this kind of issues

Comment: ember install ember-cli-tutorial-style

Answer (score 1):

In error, warning its saying to update minimatch version to 3.0.2 for that you can run the below command,
`npm install --save-dev minimatch@3.0.2`

After that you can try running `ember install ember-cli-tutorial-style`.

If this still shows error, you can directly do,

`npm install --save-dev ember-cli-tutorial-style`

Comment: I did the above, but then did: `ember install ember-cli-tutorial-style` to finally get the style. This is probably a temporary issue with their NPMs.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this does not have to do with minimatch warning.
What npm is telling you, is that it cannot find that module (in your case ember-cli-tutorial-style).
Make sure that, this npm package actually exists!